# VM can't ping localhost on ESXi 4

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, dhcp, ping, localhost

I have some problem, i have 3 VM (vm1, vm2, and vm3).
vm1 is normal. ping to internal and external is OK, DHCP is OK.
but vm2 and vm3 very strange. DHCP is OK but can't ping to internal and external.
Can't ping to localhost and to gateway ip.

Anyone know to solve this problem ?

Thanks before and after for advance.

Comment: Are you sure that DHCP is ok ? Maybe its assigning virtual private adress ? Is it Windows on it (i mean on vm2,vm3) ?

Comment: yes, continue to my last comments

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot even ping the localhost, then try to ping lo addresss 127.0.0.1 to see if that works. If not your lo interface is not up and you need to fix that. Dhcp working? Does that mean your virtual nic is getting all the network information? What does ifconfig command return by the way.

Comment: yes, DHCP is OK, cause i get an ip address, but can't ping to gateway too. its happen not just in VM, physically too.

Comment: what is the ip you got from dhcp? what is your subnet range?

Comment: i think it not VM problem, it linux problem. I use CentOS 5.7 final.

Comment: ip is 10.103.104.3 netmask is 255.255.255.0 GW is 10.103.104.1